# Deploying Angular Project in Docker - Why is my Frontend not appearing?

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have been trying to launch my MEAN stack application using docker on a DigitalOcean droplet. I have been running docker-compose up and can see my containers being successfully created, but the Angular frontend is not appearing on {{ip_from_digital_ocean}}:4200. I have also tried copying the dist folder to nginx with no luck.

Dockerfile for Angular

```
FROM node:12 as node
RUN mkdir -p /frontend
WORKDIR /frontend
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . /frontend
EXPOSE 4200
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Dockerfile for Node/Express

```
FROM node:12
RUN mkdir -p /backend
WORKDIR /backend
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And finally the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services: 
    angular:
        container_name: handi-tracker-ui
        build: ./handicap-helper
        ports:
            - '4200:4200'
    express: 
        container_name: handi-tracker-service
        restart: always
        build: ./backend
        ports: 
            - '3000:3000'
        links:
            - mongo
    mongo: 
        container_name: mongo
        image: mongo
        volumes: 
            - /mongo-volume:/data/db
        ports:
            - '27017:27017'
```

Comment: Frontend does not appear at all, doesn't it? Or you request page, and something appears?

Comment: I don't see when you Dockerfile is building your app and copying the output to the server that will be serving it.                                                                                                     Dockerfile >  `RUN npm run build:prod --verbose`  and package.json > `"build:prod": "ng build --prod --aot --extract-css"`

Comment: Nothing appears, I have attempted copying the dist from prod to nginx

Comment: @abestrad sorry I am not following (zero experience in docker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a simple image to build angular and then use the Docker multi-stage feature to create another image to host your application. Here is an example with some comments.

Frontend

```
# First Stage  
FROM node:12.18.2-alpine as build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./

# npm install is just installing dependencies of the project.
RUN npm install

# After having your dependencies resolved, you can copy the rest of the project
COPY . .

# Then, you need to run the build script of the angular app.
RUN npm run install

# Second Stage 
FROM 'your_server_image'

# Moving files, assuming the dist output is 'dist'
COPY --from=build/usr/src/app/dist /the/server/path

# For example, if you use Nginx
# COPY --from=build/usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: i will give it a go!

Comment: it looks like it is finally going through on 4200, it looks as if none of the angular material is rendering. Only seeing a blank page now.